# Fullcalendar : Is there a possibility to display 2 or more months in a row

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to display 2 or more month like the image below with fullCalendar.js :

[image]

I know that you can write your own view and I try that :

```
    views: {
        twoMonths: {
            type: 'dayGridMonth',
            duration: { months: 2 },
            buttonText: '2 month'
        }
    },
```

[image]

The problem is that it only display one full month. I don't want a 'timeline' view because I need to do holiday schedules. So the 'dayGridMonth' view will be better.

[The doc of fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible currently. If you really want that, you'd need to instantiate 3 separate calendars on the page. For the future, you can try to request this as a feature: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: Ok, i will try to find something else so. Thank you for your answer.